# Get list of SP parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm writing a function to call a stored procedure given an `IDictionary` of arguments.

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.GetTrackingInfo")]
[ResultType(typeof(Shipment))]
[ResultType(typeof(Piece))]
[ResultType(typeof(Item))]
public IMultipleResults GetTrackingInfo(IDictionary<string, object> arguments)
{
    var method = (MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();

    var argumentsArr = this.Mapping.GetFunction(method).Parameters
        .Select(p => arguments.ContainsKey(p.Name)
            ? NullableExtensions.Convert(arguments[p.Name], p.ParameterType)
            : null)
        .ToArray();

    return (IMultipleResults)this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, method, argumentsArr);
}
```

I expected `Mapping.GetFunction(method).Parameters` to return the parameters of the SP, but instead it returned the parameters of this method. Is there any simple way to get the parameters of the underlying SP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Name` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metaparameter.name.aspx) (as you've found out) returns the name of the function in the CLR space.

What you want to use is the [`MappedName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metaparameter.mappedname.aspx), defined as (emphasis mine):

> Gets the name of the **parameter in the database function**.

Note that the call to the [`Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metafunction.parameters.aspx) on the [`MetaFunction` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548787.aspx) *does* return information about the parameters of the underlying SP; it's a mapping, so it has both the SP information along with the information about the CLR representation, associated with the same [`MetaParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534371.aspx) instance.